# HTML5 expanding web banner **in Iframe** - DoubleClick for publishers

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, banner-ads, double-click-advertising

I have been asked to create an HTML5 expanding banner that will be site-served on a popular fashion website. The creative (HTML5) is to be hosted via DoubleClick for publishers (DFP).

However I am not sure how my HTML5 file will open/increase the size of the Iframe that it will sit in on the site.

I have looked up about it and can find some stuff about Iframe busters and in particular this one [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1085693?hl=en) from DFP(Google) but am not sure if it can work with HTML5 creative.

Does anyone know how I can develop and expanding HTML5 that will open the Iframe it sits in on a DFP platform?

Here is a link to what I'm creating: http://faithstaging.co.uk/html5_banner_ad_exp/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about this issue here:

DoubleClick Rich Media iframe solution
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/117857